# Nix pkgmanager: Profile path on single-user installation (non-NixOS)

Tags: nix

I tried to switch generations in the nix package manager with `nix-env --switch-generations 33`, but because I'm an idiot, I accidentally did `nix-env --switch-profile 33`, and now I can't use nix. I can manually find a `nix-env` binary in `/nix`, but I don't know where the profile originally was. There's nothing in `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user`.

I had originally installed nix in Linux Mint 21, adding the `--no-daemon` option to the installer, effectively installing nix in single-user mode. How can I figure out where my profile was?

Answer (score 0):

After having created a VM just to play with a fresh installation of nix (the package manager, not the distro), I finally figured it out. Apparently, the default profile, for a "--no-daemon" installation is `~/.local/state/nix/profiles/profile`. I wish this was documented somewhere, but at least people can find it here.

Comment: It is documented in the manual: https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/files/profiles